# Authenticating a Raspberry Pi http request

Tags: javascript, php, apache, security, raspberry-pi

I am making a Raspberry Pi kiosk using chromium. The html pages will be contained on the Pi and the information on the pages will be returned through ajax (JSON). Similar to an API. They make requests to my server using SSL. The information should be kept private and only allowed to be accessed by the Pi. There is no login to the kiosk, its kinna a plug and play thing. What type of authentication should I use to verify that only the Pi is returned the data and on one else? A rotating token stored on the Pi? Checking IP? Static token? Use Apache htaccess?

- Server is using PHP and MySQL on Apache
- Front end is HTML and JS stored on the Pi

Comment: Do you have any plans to harden the Pi itself? Seems it would be easy to connect it to a PC and extract any kind of authentication information from the client app and spoof it.

Comment: The Pi will be locked away. Not much chance of anyone getting anything from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest reliable solution is probably Apache basic auth. It's a perfectly acceptable solution combined with SSL as you already said you're using (so the password gets encrypted). There is a [setup guide here](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PasswordBasicAuth). It works very well and is easy to configure.

Then just use URLs like this:

```
https://$username:$password@www.example.com/somefile.php
```